# Custom Inventory Lookup Filter

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to make certain products available/unavailable to certain customers. Similar to Netflix's blocking some movies on some customers depending on geographical locations. I'm assuming I'll need a custom table for the inventory item and list of restricted customers. And then attach this somehow to the lookup filtering. How can I customised the inventory lookup dialog to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add PXRestrictor attribute for each selector. For example for SO301000 you should add PXRestrictor on SOLine.InventoryID. You can add it by implementing SOLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached() handler in the extension of SOOrderEntry graph.

If you would like to limit visibility all over the product for specific users,
consider using Restriction Groups, see https://help.acumatica.com/(W(19))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=ad9a42c1-ff5d-4298-86d9-683039c18512 for details.

Comment: Thanks Ilya. I think you're onto something there. Is it possible to extend the restriction groups to per Company not just per User ?

Comment: Hi Rick. Restriction groups are per user. If you want to restrict access (to some inventory items) to all users in a company - you can select all users by pressing "Select all" checkbox. 
More details on Inventory Item security can be found here: https://help.acumatica.com/(W(21))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=09c9c94d-1707-4e24-bb2c-29343e18864f

Comment: Sorry, I meant Company as Customer or Debtors. So only certain items will be available on certain customers\debtors. Not per user.

Comment: What do you mean by "certain items will be available on certain customers\debtors"? You cannot login as a "customer", you can login as a user. If you want that certain screens should hide some items in Selector controls based on a customer selected on the screen, for any user logged in - please specify in what screens (you can find screen id in URL of an Acumatica page) you want such a behavior.

Comment: SO301000 and\or AR301000. For example, Bob's PC is a company that sells PC where the Acumatica is installed. Bob's PC has some overseas customers. Some products cannot be ship overseas e.g. bulky items. Peter's Appliances is a customer based overseas. John is a user in Bob's PC. When John raises a Sales Orders for Peter's Appliances. Those bulky items should be filtered out in Inventory lookup screen. Only items available in the lookup must meet certain criterias e.g. can be shipped overseas. The logged in user - John, is not a factor here. Hope this explains it. Thanks

Comment: You should add PXRestrictor attribute for each selector. For example for SO301000 you should add PXRestrictor on SOLine.InventoryID. You can add it by implementing SOLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached() handler in the extension of SOOrderEntry graph.